# How to create custom executor class?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have numerous http tasks in different asynctask objects. I want them to run in following way. 
Take 2 threads A and B. Some tasks need to run in A and some in B. Task in a thread is run serially but thread A and B run in parallel.
I will use AsyncTask.executeonexecutor(); to execute asynctask.

(I might be able to do this using old way of creating runnable class and threads but it will need me to change a huge portion of code)

Any idea how can I make a custom executor class to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Create 2 single-threaded executors, A and B. Run some tasks with executeOnExecutor(A), others with executeOnExecutor(B).